# How to build an OCSP certificate chain for dual-stack RSA + ECC certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, ocsp

Nginx lets us use multiple certificates so that we can use both ECC and RSA certificates

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.combined.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com.key;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com-ecc.combined.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com-ecc.key;
```

However, it only lets us specify a single trusted certificate to use for OCSP stapling:

```
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/ocsp-bundle-rsa-ecc.crt;
```

Clearly we need to give it both chains of intermediate & root certs, but I can't find any documentation on whether it's supported at all, or what order these certs should be in, i.e. whether it should be:

- intermediate1
- root1
- intermediate2
- root2

or

- intermediate1
- intermediate2
- root1
- root2

or, if they need to share a root (some ECC certs are signed using an RSA root):

- intermediate1
- intermediate2
- root

or simply whether it's not possible to do OCSP with dual format certificates in nginx.

How should this certificate bundle be constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick research, and it seems the easiest answer to this "you don't build it" and it will just work :)

OSCP stapling may work fine *without* `ssl_trusted certificate` as long as..

- Your OS trusted root CA store is up-to-date (think `ca-certificates` in RedHat)
- You have `ssl_stapling on;` and `ssl_stapling_verify on;`
- Each of your certificate (ECC and RSA based) includes full chain except for root CA

nginx docs are clear that only...

> If the ssl_certificate file does not contain intermediate certificates, the certificate of the server certificate issuer should be present in the ssl_trusted_certificate file

You can actually check your stuff in SSL Labs test to confirm this - OSCP stapling does work fine without `ssl_trusted_certificate`.

So dual certificates can have working OSCP if you simply ensure best practices of placing both certificate itself and its intermediate certificate in the file defined in `ssl_certificate` and having up-to-date root CAs in your system.